# How to prefetch on a collection using Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following method that performs a fetch on my collection and then calls the `render` function to display the results.  This all works fine and it's triggered every time the user gets down to the bottom of the page.

However during this fetch I then want to prefetch the next batch of items so that the experience will be better for the user.  I'm not sure how to achieve this.  I thought about doing another `this.collection.fetch` (Check my code) and then assigning the results to a variable but I wasn't sure if this is bad practice.

Then I could maybe consult this variable to see if its got any contents the next time the user gets to the bottom of the page?

Has anyone done something similar and can give me some guidance?

```
loadItems: function() {

    var that = this;

    this.collection.fetch({
        data: {"offset": this.offset, "limit": this.limit}, 
        success: function () {
            that.render();

            that.offset += that.limit;

            //Maybe I can do another fetch here
            this.collection.fetch({
                data: {"skip": this.skip, "limit": this.limit, "sort": this.sortKey}
                success: function () {
                    //However I'm not really sure how I would get the results and assign them to a variable
                }
            });
        }
    });
},
render: function() {
    var self = this;

    _(this.collection.models).each(function(product){
        self.appendItem(product);
    }, this);
},
appendItem: function(product) {
    var productView = new ProductView({
        model: product
    });
    $(this.el).find(".products-list").append(productView.render().el);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not fetching when the main page is loaded ?

var data = collection.fetch();

When it hits the bottom you view.render(update); then update data by fetching again data = collection.fetch();

So data is keeping the collection state, when it will hit the bottom for the second time it will display what is already fetched and stored in data then fetch again and update data for the next bottom hit...

```
var data;
collection.fetch({
 success: function(model) {
    data=model.toJSON();
 }
})
```

Comment: `var data = collection.fetch();` will hold the xhr object returned by fetch, and not "data"